# Can't build C++ program using Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, build, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I think many of you are using or used to use Sublime Text 2 editor. I have strange error: C++ programs can't be built.

**My** `C++.sublime-build`**:**

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I found that when the `cmd` array contains ANY substituted expression like `${file}` or `$file`, build doesn't start. Otherwise it starts.

It doesn't matter from compiler. When I've tried `"cmd": ["notify-osd", "$file"]`, it didn't work; but with `"cmd": ["notify-osd", "sometexthere"]` it worked.

Compiling by-hand works right.

My program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

I use Ubuntu 12.04, 32bit. Version of Sublime Editor: 2.0.1.

If it isn't the place where I could ask this question, please tell me what's the right one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your C++.sublime-build file....works like a charm.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-pedantic", "-std=c++11",   "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the way to turn on C++11 compilation on sublime (also ver 3). For 12.04 use "-std=c++0x".

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a workaround solution to this problem: Use makefiles. Sublime Text 2 can run makefiles to compile c++ for you.

You would be more likely to get a better answer to this question by asking in the Sublime forums (http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/).
Even there they would probably be interested in knowing "how" it doesn't work (i.e. if nothing happens at all when pressing "Build", you might want to specify that).

Comment: This is the right place to ask such questions. Sublime is a fine editor, and naturally of interest to StOv users. The OP had problems with simple compilation of elementary code, and "workaround" by makefiles ... does not deserve the mark of accepted answer.

Comment: @PMarecki And hopefully anyone searching for the answer to this question will have the wits about them to check both the accepted answer and the top voted answer.

Comment: @PMarecki I think using makefiles is a perfectly reasonable suggestion. Given the OP accepted the answer, it seems he did too.

Answer (score 0):

It took me several hours to get C++ compiling working on Sublime Text, and I still have some slight problems (like the fact that Sublime Text can't apparently execute the program in an externe window/console).

Here's my config file:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"],

"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",

"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",

"selector": "source.c",

"shell": true,

"encoding": "latin1"

}
```

(make sure to change the encoding to utf8 if the compiler doesn't work)

Also, add the MinGW's bin folder to your OS's Path variable (look up 'environment variable' in the start menu, and then look for the Path variable).