# Sublime Text 3 C++ build system

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

Hello I messed up a little with C++ build system in Sublime Text 3 and now I can't run any program.
Here is my build system:

```
{
  "cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && open -a Terminal -e \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for help,
Nenor

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: why are you escaping all the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The only wrong think seems to be the way you write the `command`. It's not stated in the new documentation, but in the [old one](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) you can read

cmd:
*Array* containing the command to run and its desired arguments.

So, this build system should do the trick (this is the default provided):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that someone has previously reported having trouble with the `C++.sublime-build` provided by default (it's all fine on my OS X). If that's the case, consider salek's reply on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485117/cant-build-c-program-using-sublime-text-2?rq=1).